# Genesis Backcountry theme leave comment box after post issue

Tags: web-development

I run x3 Genesis sites and 2 use Backcountry Genesis child theme.
On the most recent site I setup with Backcountry I want the "Leave comment" form to display at the end of each post and it is not doing this!

Comment: Questions regarding development are no longer considered on-topic for this site.

Answer (score 0):

Tumbleweed.....

No replies. I am answering my own question. Someone on a forum (WordPress or StudioPress I don't remember exactly which) told me the comment form/box does NOT display on a homepage. It is that simple. I do not know why this is nor why it is hard to find out that this is so but this does explain the problem.